# Whats the difference between "echo" and "!echo" in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command, echo

What the difference between the command `echo` and `!echo`?

I think that with `!echo` it concatenates with the previous command but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's using `bash` history, which means `!command` will grab the most recent command that was previously executed that matches "command". Type in `history` and see what you get. They are also numbered, so you can execute a prior command by typing `!n` where `n` is the number of the command. Google "bash command history".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exclamation mark can have two meanings in bash:

1. history expansion

   ```
   !echo
   ```

   would expand to the recent line starting with "echo".
2. negation (space after `!` needed)

   `! echo` would set `$?` to 0 if the `echo` call was unsuccessful, or to 1 if it was successful.